# What neural learning algorithm could work better than backpropagation for the dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm writing a thesis where I developed a script that generates NN and precalculates weights and biases to reduce a required number of epochs. I am using feedforward and recurrent NN, applying backpropagation and stochastic gradient descent optimization, tahn activation function

These my input and target datasets.

```
      Input          Target   
Dec Inc > 0 > 1 |  0  >0    >1   
 1  -1  -1  -1  | -1  -1    -1   
 1  -1   1  -1  |  1  -1    -1    
 1  -1   1   1  |  1   1    -1   
-1   1  -1  -1  | -1   1    -1
```

Is there any other algorithm that could work better than backprop?
I just want to enrich my thesis, if you can share a reference I would really appreciate it

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will work better but you could try optimization methods based on second-order derivatives: [**L-BFGS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) or [**Newton's method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

[image]

It depends on the model structure and dataset, but I think back propagation will work better in most cases. But it could be worth trying!

If you want a reference regarding optimization methods for neural networks, refer to **[here](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/ICML2011Le_210.pdf)**.